# Adding dynamic keys in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Javascript and I'm facing a problem in adding data in the Firebase with dynamic key

this is my variable

```
 var stuID = snap.child("StudentID").val();
```

I'm adding it in this way

```
DataBaseRef.set({
          stuID : stuID

  });
```

it keeps setting is key to "stuID" instead of the actual value

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KebE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the square bracket notation, as follows:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj[stuID] = 'myValue';   //or myObj[stuID] = stuID; if it is what you want
DataBaseRef.set(myObj);
```

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I needed.